# How i sum same a column value when username is same - Laravel 5.2?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5

I have a table where i have all `winners` details of prize with `username` of which user draw the prize. Now i want to show this column when same `username` then it will show total `win_number`. I have tried some way but can not find out the proper way what i want. If i use:

```
$winners = Winner::where('id', '>=', 1)->paginate(1000);
```

Then i will show the retrieve result as winners table as in database.

**My winners table:**

[image]

**My Output:**

[image]

But want to retrieve data all with ex. if `guest` username i want show in every `guest` name beside 4(total number of win as `guest` user)

I have tried another way but its show just column `guest` where `username= guest`.

```
$winners = DB::table('winners')
             ->select(DB::raw('*'))
             ->where('id', '<>', 1)
             ->where('username', '=', 'guest')
             ->get();
```

How can i achieve, all data from winners table just if username same then i want to total number of win in beside the every username. By the way i am week in queries. Thanks in advance.

Comment: $winners = DB::table('winners')
             ->select(DB::raw('*'))
             ->where('id', '<>', 1)
             ->where('username', '=', 'guest')
             ->sum('win_number');

Comment: just add sum in your query as i write above check the query..

Comment: It won't work because username = guest. It will show just for guest username. But i want all data with sum of `win_number` beside every user.

Comment: `DB::table('winners')->sum('win_number')`

Comment: $winners = DB::table('winners')->sum('win_number');

Comment: try this it can help you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try a group by

```
DB::table('winners')->groupBy('identify_number')
   ->selectRaw('*, sum(win_number) as sum')
   ->get();
```

Comment: Its working but i have total 11 row in winners table. But in retrieve data its showing 8 row. Its have 4 guest user i need all for guest row but in every guest row beside i want win_number 4.

Comment: Your query retrieve just one guest user row with win_number 4 but i want all 4 guest user with win_number 4.

Comment: how do you differentiate the quests ?

Answer (score 0):

you can use like this

```
$data = DB::table("winners")
    ->select(DB::raw("COUNT(*) as count_row"))
    ->where('id', '<>', 1)
    ->groupBy(DB::raw("username"))
    ->get();
```

Comment: Its working and need to select all value but i have total 11 row in winners table. But in retrieve data its showing 8 row. Its have 4 guest user i need all for guest row but in every guest row beside i want win_number 4.

Answer (score 0):

use sum() of Laravel collections
https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/collections#method-sum